# What font is it that was used in this document?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I was wondering if anyone knows the name of the font used in screenshot below? Thanks in advance! [image: The proof of the "if"-part of Theorem 3.1]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: if you have the pdf you don't need to guess, pdffonts utility or fonts menu of your pdf viewer will list the fonts, see above link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be Palatino, with math from [`mathpazo`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo). Just to point out: you can also use this font with the more recent (and actively maintained) bundle [`newpx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newpx), although the math font is slightly different (the greek letters differ a bit, for example).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}
\setcounter{subsection}{2}
\subsection{The proof of the ``if''-part of Theorem 3.1}
Suppose that \(f\) satisfies multiplicative symmetries. Denote by \(\sigma(N)\) the sum of the positive divisors of \(N\). By Lemma 3.3, we have
\begin{align*}
    & \epsilon_N q^{\sigma(N)} \prod_{\substack{ad=N \\ 0\leq b<d}} \Bigl( f^{(as)} (\zeta_d^b q^{a/d}) - f^{(as)}(r) \Bigr) \\
    & = \prod_{\substack{ad=N \\ 0\leq b<d}} \biggl( 1 - \zeta_d^b q^{a/d} f^{(as)}(r) + \sum_{m=2}^\infty H_{m-1}^{(as)} \zeta_d^{bm} q^{am/d} \biggr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

## It's called [Palatino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatino).

I highly recommend to look at: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/14527) which was suggested in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697469/need-help-to-identify-a-font/697471#comment1732436_697469) comment by David Carlisle, but the top answer to that question requires you to have a PDF file with the font in it.

Fortunately, even without the PDF file I was able to recognize this font because I have used it for almost all of my papers, for example [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13583), and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.07636) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04405).

Comment: I did not look at all links, but in your first manuscript you seem to mix palatine text with computer modern math.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I did use palatino in all of those papers, but it's true that for the first paper I **also** used computer modern for the math-mode parts (still the vast majority of the paper uses palatino). mickep and I had a discussion about this [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64514380#64514380) in case anyone is interested.